# Database join vs keeping column in single table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables. One is `Employee` and another is `Role`. The `Employee` table contains `EmployeeId` and `EmployeeName`. Similarly, the `Role` table will contain `RoleId` and `RoleName` column. An employee will belong to one of several different roles.

I am new to database design and having problem figuring out if it's better to have a `RoleId` column in the `Employee` table or to create another table called `EmployeeRoleMapping` which will contain rows indicating this employee is mapped to this role. What are the pros and cons of both approach?

Comment: The `EmployeeRoleMapping` junction table approach is canonical, and likely what most on this site would recommend.  If you want to store role information in the employee table, appreciate that you might end up duplicating certain information, such as the employee name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, do you mean that there will be data duplication because of two or more employees having the same name? But won't that be the case even if there is no RoleId column? If an employee is tied to a single role at any given point, will it be an issue?

Comment: Well no, this problem goes away with the junction table approach, because there the relationship between employee and role is represented by two IDs.  The employee's metadata (name, etc.) is stored only once in a separate table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Seems you make a rather significant assumption. OP writes " An employee will belong to one of several different roles". That is a 1:1 relationship in my interpretation. Typically one would implement that by simply adding RoleID to the Employee table. A mapping table would only be needed if the relationship was 1:M - but it would be better to clarify that with OP.

Comment: @SMor, But a role may belong to several different employees. Would it still be considered a 1:1 relationship? I'm not exactly sure that's why I'm asking.

Comment: That would be 1:M, and you should only use a junction table for M:M.

Comment: If an employee has no more than 1 roles then you can keep the column in the table Employee. Still the same role be applied to more than 1 employees.

Answer (score 0):

the most important thing is that you must sure of the relationship between Employee and Role in your application.

In my point of view, an Employee may have one or many roles and vise versa one role may belong to one or many Employees. So that, we have to create a new table called `EmployeeRoles` and this table has employeed_id and Role_id.

Comment: The OP has already named its junction table `EmployeeRoleMapping`.  Re-read the question.